# Problem Copying Data from One Database (and Server) to Another (Violation of Primary Key Constraint)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get a local copy of our remote database.  I cannot do a "copy database" because it will not copy to SQLExpress.  So I tried to script with data to recreate on my local, it got all the way to the "end" 3 times and then just said "generate script failed".  So I scripted just the schema.  All tables are empty, but now I am getting "duplicate key" errors (of course at the very end), like this:

> Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__tbl_AICC__3214EC07D26FCB1E'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tbl_AICC_Results'. The duplicate key value is (1).".
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

I tried checking off "delete rows in table"  I tried checking "delete and recreate tables", then I get a cannot truncate because the table is a foreign key, but I disabled all of the constraints using this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all"
```

for those suggesting backup...It is not listed as an option:

[image]

That database is hosted on Azure, so I am not sure if that is why I cannot do a backup and restore.

because I was getting "cannot insert into read only Id", I am not getting that anymore so I could only assume that the removal worked.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: backup the remote, restore to local?

Comment: I would, but backup is not listed as an option.

Comment: SQL Server has the concept of "backups", so you don't need to create unreliable scripts like in other DB engines. Just take a copy-only backup and restore to your server.

Comment: Listed option?  Update the list.  Is this for an academic exercise?  Note that both the backup and restore can also be scripted.

Comment: No, it is not an academic exercise.  I think maybe because it is in the cloud?  This is my first time working with a database that lives on Azure.  I've found out a lot about it today, like you can't debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading this correctly - you want to move/copy from your remote Azure SQL Database to a local instance.  If so, then you need to create a BACPAC in Azure, copy that locally and use that for your local system.

See these documents:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/database-export

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database?view=sql-server-ver15